# Slice numpy array using list of coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

Consider a numpy ndarray `M` of shape (say) `(a,b,c)` and a list of coordinates `[(b0,c0),(b1,c1),...,(bn,cn)]`.

I want the following collection of vectors: `[M[:,b0,c0],M[:,b1,c1],...,M[:,bn,cn]]`.
How can I achieve this with list comprehension?

EDIT: I need a solution that works for any number of dimensions, i.e. something that returns a list like the one above also in the case (say) `M.shape = (a,b,c,d)` `and coordinates = [(b0,c0,d0),...,(bn,cn,dn)]`, and higher-dimensional cases as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't want to do this with a list comprehension. "Fancy indexing" can do the whole thing in one go. I'd recommend:

```
inds = [(b0,c0),(b1,c1),...,(bn,cn)]

#inds_array[0] = [b0, b1, b2, ...]
inds_array = np.moveaxis(np.array(inds), -1, 0)

M[np.index_exp[:] + tuple(inds_array)]
```

---

Demo:

```
>>> x, y, z = np.ogrid[:2,:4,:5]
>>> M = 100*x + 10*y + z
>>> M.shape
(2, 4, 5)
>>> inds = [(0, 0), (2, 1), (3, 4), (1, 2)]
>>> inds_array = np.moveaxis(np.array(inds), -1, 0); inds_array
array([[0, 2, 3, 1],
       [0, 1, 4, 2]])
>>> M[np.index_exp[:] + tuple(inds_array)]  # same as M[:, [0, 2, 3, 1], [0, 1, 4, 2]]
array([[  0,  21,  34,  12],
       [100, 121, 134, 112]])
```

Comment: It might help to show what that indexing expression looks like: `slice(None), ....`.  I had to look up `index_exp` to see how it's different from `s_`, and without running an example I can't picture `inds_array`.

Answer (score 5):

If you want a *list* of these vectors you can simply use:

```
[M[:,bi,ci] for bi,ci in coordinates]
```

where `coordinates` is of course your list:

```
coordinates = [(b0,c0),(b1,c1),...,(bn,cn)]
```

**EDIT**: in case you want *multivariate* slicing, you can call the `__getitem__` method with a `slice(None)` and the remaining indices:

```
[M.[(slice(None),*coord)] for coord in coordinates]
```

for [python-3.5](/questions/tagged/python-3.5); or:

```
[M[(slice(None),)+coord] for coord in coordinates]
```

for other [python](/questions/tagged/python) versions.

Comment: Dang it! beat me by a few seconds.

Comment: Thanks! This of course works, but I realized that I simplified my problem too much when writing the question. Let me edit it.

Comment: @Ziofil: but you explicitly ask to use list comprehension. didn't dv btw.

Comment: @Ziofil: does the updated example works (in Python-3.5)?

Comment: Downvote for calling `.__getitem__(` directly. There only reason to do that is `super`, and this is not that