# Slice pytorch tensor using coordinates tensor without loop

Tags: pytorch, tensor

I have a tensor `T` with dimension (`d1 x d2 x d3 x ... dk`) and a tensor `I` with dimension (`p x q`). Here, `I` contains coordinates of `T` but `q < k`, each column of `I` corresponds to a dimension of `T`. I have another tensor `V` of dimension `p x di x ...dj` where `sum([di, ..., dj]) = k - q`. (`di, .., dj`) corresponds to missing dimensions from `I`. I need to perform `T[I] = V`

A specific example of such problem using `numpy` array posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537956/slice-numpy-array-using-list-of-coordinates)<sup>[1]</sup>.

The [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538465/6422069)<sup>[2]</sup> uses [fancy indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html)<sup>[3]</sup> which relies on `numpy.index_exp`. In case of `pytorch` such option is not available. Is there any alternative way to mimic this in `pytorch` without using loops or casting tensors to `numpy` array?

Below is a demo:

```py
import torch
t = torch.randn((32, 16, 60, 64)) # tensor

i0 = torch.randint(0, 32, (10, 1)).to(dtype=torch.long) # indexes for dim=0
i2 = torch.randint(0, 60, (10, 1)).to(dtype=torch.long) # indexes for dim=2

i = torch.cat((i0, i2), 1) # indexes
v = torch.randn((10, 16, 64)) # to be assigned

# t[i0, :, i2, :] = v ?? Obviously this does not work
```

[1] [Slice numpy array using list of coordinates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42537956/slice-numpy-array-using-list-of-coordinates)

[2] https://stackoverflow.com/a/42538465/6422069

[3] https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.s_.html

Comment: Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @Ivan added an example

Comment: You can use `slice(None)` instead of `np.index_exp[:]`.

Comment: @aretor I am dealing with pytorch tensor and want to avoid casting tensor to numpy. If the tensor is in GPU casting means transferring the tensor to ram and finally again transferring it back to GPU.

Comment: Can't you use something like `t[(i0, slice(None), i2, slice(None))]`? If I got it correctly, it should make the job. Everything still resides in the GPU. Let me know

Comment: @aretor t[(i0, slice(None), i2, slice(None))] = v

RuntimeError: shape mismatch: value tensor of shape [10, 16, 64] cannot be broadcast to indexing result of shape [10, 1, 16, 64]

Comment: I forgot to flatten the indices, this works: `t[(i0.flatten(), slice(None), i2.flatten(), slice(None))] = v`

Comment: @aretor, Can you write it as answer, so that I can mark it as solution?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242954/discussion-between-aretor-and-tachyon).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some discussion in the comments, we arrived at the following solution:

```py
import torch
t = torch.randn((32, 16, 60, 64)) # tensor

# indices
i0 = torch.randint(0, 32, (10,)).to(dtype=torch.long) # indexes for dim=0
i2 = torch.randint(0, 60, (10,)).to(dtype=torch.long) # indexes for dim=2

v = torch.randn((10, 16, 64)) # to be assigned

t[(i0, slice(None), i2, slice(None))] = v
```